# how to find/implement a good hash function for bitset

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am trying to use unordered_map in which the key (stored in bitset) is generated by Morton encoding. I tested several cases when the key is in the range of 2^0-2^6, 2^3-2^9 (the last 3 bits are zero), 2^6-2^12 (the last 6 bits are zero), and 2^9-2^15 (the last 9 bits are zero).

When I use the default hash function for bitset provided by visual studio, everything seems good. The time for looking up an element in the unordered_map for all the cases is at the same order and increase monotonically with the size of the container.

When I tried to reduce the time for looking up an element, something went wrong. I use the hash function

```
class my_bitset_hash
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const bitset<64>& key) const
    {
        size_t hashVal = 0;
        hashVal = key.to_ullong();
        return hashVal;
    }
};
```

The time for looking up an element when the key is in the range of 2^9-2^15 is at least two orders of magnitudes greater than that when the key is in the range of 2^0-2^6, even if the size of the unorder_map is the same. As far as I know, if there's no collision, time consumption for looking up should be the lowest and the time complexity should be O(1). In addition, all of the cases need more time for looking up compared to those using the default function.

Does anyone have some ideas about this and how to find a good hash function for bitset?

Thank you

Comment: That seems to be in time ranges where such differences can easily be just noise. Have you profiled on big enough inputs? Has your machine had the same load for all the test runs (having a browser or a game running in the background can change a lot). Have you used a profiler to find out where this difference occurs exactly? (Maybe to_ullong() is faster for very short bitsets... There are many possibilities)

Comment: According to [some sources](http://web.archive.org/web/20160930025012/http://www.crashedtestdummy.com/?p=54) Visual Studio's implementation of unordered_map only takes the lower bits of the hash value, so the result is obvious. Either switch to another hash table or switch to another hash map implementation.

Comment: Assumes that your "in the range of 2^9-2^15" keys are (mostly) congruent modulo 2^(some small number).

Comment: You could test this by adding `hashVal <<= 32;` to your hash function. if what @user202729 says is the case for you, this should kill the performance of both of your test ranges.

Comment: Thank you all. I think that's the case since inputs are generated based on the first case by << operation. I will try to find other hash tables.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have some ideas about this and how to find a good hash function for bitset?

Try different hash functions.

If your dictionary stays immutable once it has been created using run-time data, try brute-forcing the hash function seed.

An example that tries to minimize collisions:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct Stats {
    static int constexpr BINS = 8;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t buckets = 0;
    double load_pct = 0;
    double collision_pct = 0;
    unsigned collisions[BINS] = {};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Stats const s) {
    o << "size: " << s.size << ", ";
    o << "buckets: " << s.buckets << ", ";
    o << "load: " << std::round(s.load_pct) << "%, ";
    o << "collisions: " << std::round(s.collision_pct) << "% [";
    for(auto const& bin : s.collisions)
        o << bin << ',';
    return o << "]\n";
}

template<class C>
Stats stats(C const& c) {
    Stats s;
    s.size = c.size();
    s.buckets = c.bucket_count();
    s.load_pct = 100. * c.size() / c.bucket_count();

    size_t collisions = 0;
    for(auto bucket_idx = c.bucket_count(); bucket_idx--;) {
        auto elements_in_bucket = std::distance(c.begin(bucket_idx), c.end(bucket_idx));
        if(elements_in_bucket > 1) {
            ++collisions;
            ++s.collisions[std::min<unsigned>(Stats::BINS - 1, elements_in_bucket - 2)];
        }
    }
    s.collision_pct = 100. * collisions / c.size();

    return s;
}

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function
struct Fnv1a32 {
    static constexpr unsigned BASIS = 16777619;
    static constexpr unsigned PRIME = 2166136261;

    unsigned const state_;

    static constexpr unsigned hash(void const* key, size_t len, unsigned state) noexcept {
        unsigned char const* p = static_cast<unsigned char const*>(key);
        unsigned char const* const e = p + len;
        for(; p < e; ++p)
            state = (state ^ *p) * PRIME;
        return state;
    }

public:
    constexpr Fnv1a32(unsigned seed = 0)
        : state_(seed ? hash(&seed, sizeof seed, BASIS) : BASIS)
    {}

    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, unsigned> operator()(T key) const {
        return hash(&key, sizeof key, state_);
    }
};

int main() {
    // Using std::hash.
    std::unordered_set<unsigned> s;
    for(unsigned n = 1000; n--;)
        s.insert(static_cast<unsigned>(std::rand()) << 6);
    std::cout << "std::hash:    " << stats(s);

    // Using Fnv1a32.
    std::unordered_set<unsigned, Fnv1a32> s2(s.bucket_count());
    s2.insert(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << "Fnv1a32:      " << stats(s2);

    // Brute-force Fnv1a32 seed.
    double best_collision_pct = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    unsigned best_seed = 0;
    for(unsigned seed = 0; seed < 10000; ++seed) {
        std::unordered_set<unsigned, Fnv1a32> s3(s2.bucket_count(), Fnv1a32{seed});
        s3.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
        auto const stats3 = stats(s3);
        if(stats3.collision_pct < best_collision_pct) {
            best_collision_pct = stats3.collision_pct;
            best_seed = seed;
        }
    }

    // Using Fnv1a32 with the best seed.
    std::unordered_set<unsigned, Fnv1a32> s4(s2.bucket_count(), Fnv1a32{best_seed});
    s4.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    std::cout << "Fnv1a32 best: "  << stats(s4);
}
```

Output:

```
std::hash:    size: 1000, buckets: 1493, load: 67%, collisions: 21% [152,46,6,1,0,0,0,0,]
Fnv1a32:      size: 1000, buckets: 1613, load: 62%, collisions: 21% [177,29,3,1,0,0,0,0,]
Fnv1a32 best: size: 1000, buckets: 1741, load: 57%, collisions: 17% [135,24,5,1,0,0,0,0,]
```

Another metric you may like to minimize in a similar way is lookup time.

For `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map`, lookup time is probably a function of `α*buckets + β*collisions + γ*hashtime`, i.e. the lookup time grows with:

- The number of buckets - more buckets lead to more CPU cache misses.
- The number of collisions - when different elements end up in the same bucket. The standard containers buckets are linked lists, so that each collision requires following the list to the next element, which is a potential CPU cache miss; and another key comparison.
- With hash function CPU time.

You can also try different hash-tables, like [`skarupke::flat_hash_map`](https://probablydance.com/2017/02/26/i-wrote-the-fastest-hashtable/) and [C++Now 2018: You Can Do Better than std::unordered_map: New Improvements to Hash Table Performance](https://youtu.be/M2fKMP47slQ), which doesn't use link lists for collision resolution and often provides best performance.

Be aware that hash-table performance depends a lot on the keys, hash function and size, so that a generic benchmark may not reflect performance on your particular workload. You need to benchmark it on your actual workload/dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tested several hash functions (i.e. Knuth multiplication, division, mid square, FVN-1, FVN-1a, MurmurHash, CityHash) for unordered_map with elements of 1.5m, 4.0m and 8.3m. Lowest lookup time is achieved when hashVal = key. The difference in memory usage for all the cases is within 5 % and the load is the  same (75% - 98%) for the same number of elements. It is noted that when hashVal = key, collisions are from 3% to 25% (should it be 0%?). I think I'd better wirte my own hash map instead of using the default one provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: @Zhengliang Find answers to your follow-up questions and more here: https://bigdata.uni-saarland.de/publications/p249-richter.pdf Also, study those links I posted before implementing your own hash table, they are quite insightful.